Setting quarkus.http.auth.permission.authenticated.enabled value through Docker Compose
I'm using Quarkus 2.15.3.Final and I ran into an issue.
I have an Auth Library where I have the following dependencies:
implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-jackson'
implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-jwt'
implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-openapi'

My other Quarkus REST API services are using this auth library as a Gradle dependency.
My goal is to dynamically disable endpoint security checks using Docker Compose in those services.
In my application.properties file of the auth library I have the following default settings
quarkus.http.auth.permission.authenticated.enabled=true
quarkus.http.auth.permission.authenticated.paths=/*
quarkus.http.auth.permission.authenticated.policy=authenticated

In my Docker Compose file of the service using the auth library as a dependency, I have the following setup where I inject env vars to disable security (excerpt)
access:
  image: access-service:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  ports:
    - "8097:8080"
  depends_on:
    - infinispan
  networks:
    - shared-net
  environment:
    QUARKUS_HTTP_AUTH_PERMISSION_AUTHENTICATED_ENABLED: false

The problem is that security is still enabled. It is only disabled if I disable it through application properties in the library itself and recompile / rebuild the project.

not sure why the downvote and also the close action? https://quarkus.io/version/2.16/guides/security-authorize-web-endpoints-reference#disabling-permissions states that it should be possible what I want to do.

The property is a build time property thus you can't change it at runtime

Permissions can be reenabled at runtime with a system property or environment variable, such as: -Dquarkus.http.auth.permission.permit1.enabled=true https://quarkus.io/version/2.16/guides/security-authorize-web-endpoints-reference#disabling-permissions

And I don't see this property as build only in the list: https://quarkus.io/version/2.16/guides/all-config
